# How to drop the first columns in multi-index Dataframe under seconde level exclude some columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Here are my dataframe. I want to drop the 'YTD2017' columns in level 1 in red exclude the green because the number is what I need.

I know the 'drop' function, and tried to put it in my programe. However, all "YTD2017" have dropped including the green area.

So, how to drop the red area and keep the green area. In other words, is there any way to drop the colmuns according to my passed column name without any impact for other columns?

Thanks.

`overall.drop('YTD2017',axis=1,level = 1 ,inplace = True)`

[image: this is my dataframe structure including sex or seven columns in level 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify values in [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) for droping:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['YTD2017', 'two', 'YTD2017', 'two', 'YTD2017', 'two', 'YTD2017', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns=mux)
print (df)
first      bar          baz          foo          qux     
second YTD2017  two YTD2017  two YTD2017  two YTD2017  two
0          NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN

df = (df.loc[:, ~df.columns.get_level_values(0).isin(['foo','qux']) | 
                (df.columns.get_level_values(1) != 'YTD2017')])
print (df)

first      bar          baz       foo  qux
second YTD2017  two YTD2017  two  two  two
0          NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Or create tuples of both levels values for [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.drop([('foo','YTD2017'), ('qux','YTD2017')], axis=1)
```

Comment: For the second way,  because  it is a screenshot, I need to drop maybe 7-9 or more columns. Therefore, it is inconvenient for me to code... Can I use other ways to drop the columns using like "tilde" function. For example, using "~" and drop funciton to reverse delete the column that I don't need?

Comment: @MaxxiHuang - `drop` with `~` is not implemented, for `~` is possible use only my first solution